# how to get axios to return the object instead of promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, weather-api

currently, my code is returning a promise I need it to return the object that It is getting from the API call, how would do that?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';

const getWeatherData = async (city,country) => {
    // const result=await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=180941f68139fba12f166dc35d9b688b`)
    // return result;
    
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=180941f68139fba12f166dc35d9b688b`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data;
      
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}

export default getWeatherData;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=180941f68139fba12f166dc35d9b688b`,
  });
  return response.data;
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

You can rewrite your axios call this way since your function is flagged as async.

async functions always return promises. Within async functions, you can use **await** infront of other async functions or functions that return promises.